# Reg ex to validate a string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use regular expression to validate a string.

```
RegEx:  "Coord=\\(.*\\);?"
```

Issue: I am not able to find reg ex for following inputs and expected output

```
1. Input:  Coord=(1,1)  -- Expected output: True
2. Input:  Coord=(1,1);  -- Expected output: True
3. Input:  Coord=(1,1):  -- Expected output: False
4. Input:  Coord=(1,1)abc  -- Expected output: False
5. Input:  Coord=(1,1);abc  -- Expected output: True
```

Any thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alternate `";"` with the end of the input to reach your goal:

```
String[] inputs = {
        "Coord=(1,1)",// -- Expected output: True
        "Coord=(1,1);",// -- Expected output: True
        "Coord=(1,1):",// -- Expected output: False
        "Coord=(1,1)abc",// -- Expected output: False
        "Coord=(1,1);abc"// -- Expected output: True
};
//                                              | this is the important bit
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Coord=\\(\\d,\\d\\)(;|$)");
for (String input: inputs) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    System.out.printf("%s found? %b%n", input, m.find());
}
```

**Output**

```
Coord=(1,1) found? true
Coord=(1,1); found? true
Coord=(1,1): found? false
Coord=(1,1)abc found? false
Coord=(1,1);abc found? true
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj the reason why it matches the last `String` is because I use `find`, not `matches`. Obviously I don't want to be using `matches` in this context.

Comment: yes, it's because of find. But it won't check for the chars present next to `;`

Comment: @AvinashRaj you are correct, it won't. I don't think that matters here. If I interpret the OP's question correctly, the importance is whether `;` is present or not. If so, whichever character follows is irrelevant. If not, the input must end. My interpretation might be wrong though.